# Setting settimer() and SIGALRM while condition variable is not signaled

Tags: c, multithreading, time, signals, condition-variable

I have some practical questions about the settimer() and SIGALRM and how they work .

Let's say that I have some threads created: (EDITED)

```py
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h> 
#include <signal.h> 

pthread_mutex_t lock;
pthread_cond_t cond=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void timer_handler (int signum)
{
  printf ("\n[WAITING LINE] All our assistants are busy at the moment,we apologize. Please wait on the line\n");
}

void* threadFunc(void* arg){

        struct itimerval timer;
        if (signal(SIGALRM, (void (*)(int)) timer_handler) == SIG_ERR) {
            perror("Unable to catch SIGALRM");
            exit(1);
        }
        timer.it_value.tv_sec =1;
        timer.it_value.tv_usec = 0;


    while(mycond){
        if(setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, &timer, NULL)){
            perror("error calling setitimer()");
            exit(1);
        }

        pthread_cond_wait(&cond1,&lock);

        //doing other things that take significant time
    }


}

int main(){

//initializing mutex
....

//creating the threads
....
//waiting the threads to join
....
return 0;

}
```

I don't get the message I was supposed to see displayed every 20 msec. 
In the example I followed a while(1) was implemented after the settimer but
I can't do that because I want this message displayed while my thread waits for the condition signal. 
It doesn't really matter what is implemented in the rest code , let's assume it takes far more time than 20ms to finish and signal the condition.

What should I do to take the timer_handler message every 20ms while the condition is not signaled yet?

I am new to using both condition variables and settimer() so any help to understand them and solve any misunderstaning would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

If all your threads are blocked, the virtual timer's clock will not be running.
You might need to switch to `ITIMER_REAL`. (Also beware that you shouldn't be using async-signal unsafe functions such as `printf` inside a signal handler.)

Comment: I just edited the code . Now I get the message only one time and only in one thread . I want to get  that message from every thread and multiple times . So how can I do that ?
Also , what can I use instead of the printf for my timer handler?

Comment: @FloraBiletsiou If you want repeated signals, set `it_interval` in addition to `it_value`. Having the signal fire off on every thread isn't so trivial, at least I can't think of a simple POSIX solution off the top of my head. `printf` can be replaced with `write(1,...)`.